# Duplicate Facebook notifications

Tags: notifications, facebook

OK I am a non tech, old generation guy, using an HTC Android phone. Just recently when Facebook posts to my phone, not only do I get the usual tone to alert me to a posting, a split second later I get a bell sound, a bell shaped icon, and the text "xx also commented on his post https://m.facebook.com/  meaning that I have two alerts for the posting. It's only started doing this recently.

Why is it doing this (duplication) and how can I stop it (irritating!)

Thanks

Comment: More than likely you have two different apps connected to your Facebook account.  Probably the official Facebook app, and some sort of social media aggregator.  If your version of Android is new enough you may be able to hide notifications for one, or otherwise go into the app and disable notifications.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have used Chrome to log into Facebook.

Go to Chrome>Menu>Settings>Site Settings>Notifications, and disable Facebook from there.

Comment: Well not sure I've done "exactly" as above (!) but I've certainly turned something off! I'll await a FB posting to see whether it makes any difference. Thanks to you and the others :)